# Sorting a C# List by multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting, combobox

I have a question on sorting a list by multiple columns. In the following sample, even though I sorted to show `None, A First Description, B Second...`, the list still prints in the order it was inserted.

```
List<MySample> samples = new List<MySample>();

samples.Add(new MySample { SortOrder = 1, Data = "A First Description", Description = "A First Description" });
samples.Add(new MySample { SortOrder = 1, Data = "C Third Description", Description = "C Third Description" });
samples.Add(new MySample { SortOrder = 1, Data = "B Second Description", Description = "B Second Description" });
samples.Add(new MySample { SortOrder = 0, Data = "None", Description = "None" });
samples.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder).ThenBy(a => a.Description).ToList();

foreach (var item in samples)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

public class MySample
{
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

If I change my code to do the following, then it prints in the desired order.

```
samples = samples.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder).ThenBy(a => a.Description).ToList();
```

Can the ordering be done without assigning(like above)?

FYI, this example is not actual code. I need to databind this list to a `ComboBox` in `WPF` through code behind using `FrameworkElementFactory`.

Thanks for your help!

**Update with my approach:**

```
var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(<My list to be sorted>);
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SortOrder", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Description", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The above did the trick in the UI. I thank all for the fast answers.

Comment: `List` provides a `Sort` function that doesn't require assignment, but it's more complicated because it involves writing you own Comparer.

Comment: One basic question. All the answers were very helpful. I am not sure how I choose the correct answer in this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because `OrderBy` does not transform the object it is called on, instead it returns a new result. You should use it like this:

```
samples = samples.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder).ThenBy(a => a.Description).ToList();
```

This is the way the `OrderBy` function works. Why would you need it to work the other way, especially for just a few extra characters.

You *could* make it work, by creating your own extension methods that do the same thing except work on the reference to the object rather than creating a new result, but this is not worth the trouble at all.

---

If you need something though, you could just wrap the LINQ in an extension method like so:

```
public static void MyOrderBy(this List<MySample> list)
{
    list = list.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder).ThenBy(a => a.Description).ToList();
}
```

and the use it like so:

```
samples.MyOrderBy();
```

It's just an idea though, I don't know if it will work, or if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: Thanks for your feeedback. In the actual code, I can't assign the list with the orderby as it is part of an object that we can't change. I am thinking if the sort comparer will give me the required functionality(as Kendall's comment)? The basic goal is don't change the original object but sort it for display as the UI needs it. Not sure if I explained my constraint clearly. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @isakavis: I have made an edit, it's just an idea, but maybe it will help you

Comment: This will not work, as `list` is not a `ref` parameter; i.e., you are only assigning a new list to the local copy within the method `MyOrderBy`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `List`, you can do it the old school way:

```
samples.Sort((s1, s2) => {
    int compare = s1.SortOrder.CompareTo(s2.SortOrder);
    if (compare != 0) return compare;
    compare = s1.Description.CompareTo(s2.Description);
    return compare;
});
```

But I'd probably stick with LINQ. Much easier to read.

Comment: Yes. This has the advantage of doing an in-place sorting and does not create a new list as the LINQ approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your example to:

```
//other code above...
samples.Add(new MySample { SortOrder = 0, Data = "None", Description = "None" });
foreach (var item in samples.OrderBy(a => a.SortOrder).ThenBy(a => a.Description))
//other code below...
```

Note that `samples` is unchanged by the ordering - only the order for that particular loop-through is set.

If neither of these are acceptable, please explain your need in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just for an alternative, "please don't do this unless nothing else fits" route, you *could* add a new property to sort on an amalgamation:

```
class NoReallyThisIsACodeSmell
{
    public string SortPlusDescription
    {
           return string.Concat(SortOrder, Description);
    }
}
```

Comment: I you're going this route (which as you said, "don't do this"), you'll want to format that SortOrder value so the number of digits is always the same, like `string.Concat(SortOrder.ToString("0000000000")`, Description) - your values would be things like `0000000123ABC` and `0000000012CDE`.

Comment: @JoeEnos Good point - I have patience limitations when posting answers from my phone :)